# Output to file c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, filewriter, apriori

I am using the Apriori Algorithm to get strong rules. So far I have got them in a list box(program was found online). However now I would like to save the output to a txt file. So far all I have been getting in the .txt file is "AprioriAlgorithm.Rule". It is getting the correct number of rules, thus repeating the "AprioriAlgorithm.Rule for the number of rules. For example, if I have 12 strong rules, I get AprioriAlgoritm.Rule for 12 times in the txt file.

```
namespace WPFClient
{
[Export(typeof(IResult))]
public partial class Result : Window, IResult
{
    public Result()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Show(Output output)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("strongrules.txt", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        this.DataContext = output;
        for (int x = 0; x < output.StrongRules.Count; x++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(output.StrongRules[x]);
        }

        this.ShowDialog();
        sw.Close();

    }
  }
}
```

And this is the output class.

```
namespace AprioriAlgorithm
{
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Output
{
    #region Public Properties

    public IList<Rule> StrongRules { get; set; }

    public IList<string> MaximalItemSets { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> ClosedItemSets { get; set; }

    public ItemsDictionary FrequentItems { get; set; } 

    #endregion
}
}
```

Comment: This isn't a question. Please summarize what you want in one sentence that  ends with "?". (You can elaborate as much as you want afterwards.)

Comment: You also don't need to use the FileStream. Instead you could use a string builder to build up your text, then output it to your file using the File helper class in System.IO -> `File.WriteAllText(outputPath, stringBuilder.ToString());`

Comment: @StephenPorter: Why create a `StringBuilder` and then write to file? It isn't any more efficient, and if your output is very large you could run out of memory. There are many ways to avoid having to deal with the `FileStream` directly (for example, using LINQ and `File.WriteAllLines`), but the `StringBuilder` approach isn't a particularly good alternative.

Comment: @JimMischel It's always case by case. There's nothing wrong with using streams, this is just an alternative. If you have a huge data set and want to use streams, by all means go for it. I tend to say "Take the Martin Fowler approach" meaning that, usually efficiency means cryptic code which isn't easily maintainable, and easily maintainable code usually means less efficiency, thus, find the common ground between the two based on the current problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this (other than overriding `ToString`) is to output the individual properties:

```
var rule = output.StringRules[x];
sw.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", rule.RuleName, rule.RuleDescription);
```

Or, using the [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) feature of C#:

```
sw.WriteLine($"{rule.RuleName}: {rule.RuleDescription}");
```

You'd want to use this if you can't or don't want to override `ToString`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing object of type `Rule` instead of `string` to the `WriteLine` method you have to specify what exactly you want to output.

You need to override the `ToString()` method of your `Rule` class in order to do that.

```
public class Rule
{
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    public string RuleDescription { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}: {1}", RuleName, RuleDescription);
    }
}
```

As [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zcc928k(v=vs.110).aspx) says

> Writes the text representation of an object by calling the ToString method on that object, followed by a line terminator to the text string or stream.